# Grocery crud delete function in edit form

Tags: function, grocery-crud

Would it be possible to put a delete function when in edit page? I want to add it inline to the other buttons at the bottom of the edit form.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to make that.

When you will click the button your function should send request to extra controller function.

This function must to delete row and send success answer. when JS function get answer you can to redirect to the list page.